# Deque to string in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, string, deque

In Python2 I was able to do something similar to:

```
frames = deque(maxlen=xyz)
framesString = ''.join(frames)
```

In Python3 I get an error.

How should I change it in order to get a string representing the deque object?

Thanks in advance,
G.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Python official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html), you can use `deque` like this:

```py
from collections import deque

# With an infinite length
frames = deque('ytreza')
''.join(frames)
# It will display 'azerty'

# With a maximum length
frames = deque('ytreza', maxlen=3)
''.join(frames)
# It will display 'aze'

# With no input
assert len(deque(maxlen=3)) == 0
''.join(deque(maxlen(3)))
# It will display an empty string
```

If content of the `deque` is `bytes`, a str conversion should be performed, with an expression generator for example.

```py
''.join(str(element) for element in my_deque)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have and I get the error... frames is a deque object. 
The second line of code that I pasted is exactly the ''.join(frames)
is the code that you pasted for Python 3? I read there are some implementation differences between v2 and v3

Comment: I use Python 3.7.5

Comment: from sys import version; print(version); -> 3.7.5 (default, Nov  1 2019, 02:16:23)

Comment: all_audio_data = ''.join(prev_audio) 

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found

prev_audio is a deque object, intialised with:

prev_audio = deque(maxlen=self.previous_audio_seconds * chunks_per_second)


frames is filled in with a pyaudio stream.

Comment: I guess problem is coming from your data. What does print(prev_audio), print(type(prev_audio)), print(len(prev_audio)) say?

Comment: Type: <class 'collections.deque'>

Len: 5

Comment: ''.join(str(x) for x in prev_audio) should solve the problem

Comment: It is just a bytes/str conversion problem, not really related to deque

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it solved your problem, you can accept it!

Comment: I got to the same conclusion but I addressed it by doing: b''.join(frames) .... which one is better?

Comment: b''.join will return bytes. ''.join(str(x) for x in prev_audio) will return str. It depends on what you want to do...

Comment: ok. it makes sense. I will accept your answer for the good support and help!!! thanks!